# Search by domain in LDAP Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, ldap, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

I don't know if anyone has used the LDAP library to access the active directory... is it possible to search using the domain? in the "eFilter" variable when I pass the user "emujica" it manages to obtain the user but if I pass it the domain, for example "domain\emujica" it fails to obtain the user... Does anyone know? How can I do it?

```
            DefaultValuesAuthenticationSourceDecorator as = new DefaultValuesAuthenticationSourceDecorator();

        as.setDefaultUser(userDn);
        as.setDefaultPassword(password);

        LdapTemplate ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
        AbstractContext abstractContextMapper = new AbstractContext();
        ldapTemplate.setIgnorePartialResultException(true);

        //Search 
        ldapTemplate.search(DistinguishedName.EMPTY_PATH, eFilter.toString(), SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE, abstractContextMapper);
```